# email data from sharepoint list to specific people

Tags: sharepoint-server, email, splistitem

I have a sp 2010 cutom list. Whenever the list gets updated, an email should be sent to some specific people and body of the email should be taken from "messageList" I searched net, most of the solutions suggests workflow. i dont want to use that since the solution has to deployed to many enviornments.

How to do it.

Below is my event for item added.

```
Public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        base.ItemAdded(properties);
        try
        {
            if (string.Equals(properties.ListTitle, DocLibTitle, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {

                //string line = string.Empty;
                SPWeb web = properties.Web;
                if (properties.AfterUrl.EndsWith(".csv", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    SPFile file = web.GetFile(properties.AfterUrl);
                    if (file.Exists)
                    {
                        SPList calendarList = web.Lists.TryGetList(CalendarListTitle);
                        SPList messageList = web.Lists.TryGetList(MessageListTitle);

                        if (calendarList != null)
                        {
                            StreamReader content;
                            content = new StreamReader(file.OpenBinaryStream());
                            var data = Parse(content);

                            foreach (var fieldValues in data)
                            {
                                SPListItem item = calendarList.Items.Add();

                                item["ChangeOrderNumber"] = fieldValues[0];
                                item["Requestor"] = fieldValues[1];
                                item["ImplementationStartDate"] = fieldValues[2];
                                item["ImplementationEndDate"] = fieldValues[3];
                                item["COStatus"] = fieldValues[4];
                                item["Assignee"] = fieldValues[5];
                                item["OrderSummary"] = fieldValues[6];
                                item["OrderDescription"] = fieldValues[7];
                                item["Justification"] = fieldValues[8];
                                item["COURL"] = fieldValues[9];
                                item.Update();

                                SPListItem messageItem = messageList.Items.Add();

                                messageItem["SendEmailTo"] = item["Requestor"];
                                messageItem["SendEmailCC"] = item["Requestor"];
                                messageItem["EmailBody"] = item["OrderSummary"];
                                messageItem.Update();

                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is the question? How to send mail? Use SPUtility.SendEmail() method.

Comment: thanks Alexander for pointing that out. I somehow totally forgot this approach.

Comment: You welcome. But SPUtility.SendEmail() method can't send attachmnents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right SP doesn't allow to send you attachments from code so instead use Plain .NET classes and write the code here is a sample you may find helpful. You can attach multiple attachments by repeating add() method.

```
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
            mail.From = new MailAddress("your_email_address@gmail.com");
            mail.To.Add("to_address");
            mail.Subject = "Test Mail - 1";
            mail.Body = "mail with attachment";

            System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment;
            attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment("your attachment file");
            mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);

            SmtpServer.Port = 587;
            SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
            SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

            SmtpServer.Send(mail);
```